# Django filtering based on data

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm using django to develop a web app. Right now I am trying to make a page that will initially render a blank form and all data objects of a certain model, and then once the user submits the form, will then filter the objects displayed to show those that have the desired attributes.

My form class is as follows

```
class AreaForm(forms.Form):
    seating = forms.IntegerField(label='Seating', default=False)
    whiteboards = forms.BooleanField(label='Whiteboards', default=False)
    outlets = forms.IntegerField(label='Outlets', default=False)
    tables = forms.IntegerField(label='Tables', default=False)
```

And the view for this page thus far is

```
def search(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = NameForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid(): 
            # do filtering logic here somehow
            return render(request, 'SpotMe/search.html', {'form': form}) # ????
    else:
        return render(request, 'SpotMe/search.html', {}) # ????
```

I'm as of yet unsure how to implement the templates page. Am I headed in completely the wrong direction?

Comment: Are you trying to add/edit any data in your DB, or are you just trying to filter results? If it is the former, then `POST` would be appropriate. If the latter is the case, then I can help you in using a `GET` request.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I am trying to do the latter.

Answer (score 0):

To show the form empty and do some logic when user post data, you need to pass the form to the template and it'll render empty if there is not post data.

### view.py

```
def search(request):
    form = AreaForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid(): 
            # do filtering logic here somehow

     return render(request, 'SpotMe/search.html', {'form': form})
```

### search.html

```
.....
{{ form.as_p }}
.....
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your reply to my question below your original post, this is an easy solution that will show all data object of a model, and then you can use an input and submit it from a template to filter the results on the same page.

Note: Substitute `MODEL` for your actually model name. You don't need a form if you are looking to filter results (it is an extra, unnecessary step).

```
def search(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        if request.GET.get('seating_no'):
            seating_no = request.GET.get('seating_no')
            queryset = MODEL.objects.filter(seating=seating_no)
        else:
            queryset = MODEL.objects.all()
        return render(request, 'SpotMe/search.html', {'queryset': queryset})
```

and in your `SpotMe/search.html` you can have a `<form><input name="seating_no" /></form>` and submit button that will lead to the same URL, and make the input name(s) into whatever you want to capture via `request.GET.get()`